# Changing hotkeys when using "find all" in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In VSCode, when using the "Find all" functionality by pressing `ctrl+shift+f`, I'd like to have two quality-of-life improvements:

1. I'd like to be able to just press `down` to get to the result field, without having to press `tab` 6 times.
2. I'd like to be able to exit the "Find all" section and return to the editor view by just pressing `esc`.

Can this be done via the shortcut system in VSCode? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command `search.action.focusNextSearchResult` that will take you to the first result.  By default, it is bound to <kbd>F4</kbd>.  But you could change that to:

```
{
  "key": "down",
  "command": "search.focus.nextInputBox",
  "when": "inputBoxFocus && searchViewletVisible || inSearchEditor && inputBoxFocus"
}
```

---

For the switch focus to the last active editor part of your question, try this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "escape",
  "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
  "when": "searchViewletVisible"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark. I added your suggestions into my keybindings.json. Unfortunately this isn't working as I'd hope. Any time I press "down" it jumps around now, in any screen. if I change the || to && in the "when" field then it doesn't seem to work at all. And the escape action flat out doesn't work - the focus is stuck on the search edit box - I'm trying to get directly to the code editor.

Comment: Alright, I played around with it myself - you helped me figure it out. Below the correct way to make it work. If you adapt your answer I'll accept it as soon as it's possible (in 17h)

{
        "key": "down",
        "command": "search.focus.nextInputBox",
        "when": "inputBoxFocus && searchViewletVisible || inSearchEditor && inputBoxFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "escape",
        "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
        "when": "searchViewletVisible"
    }

Comment: I made your changes but I tested my original version several times.  I thought you wanted to go to the "result field" - which I interpreted as the search results not the `nextInputBox`.  Glad you got it working as you like.